# Xpath [contains(text(),] doesn't find the element

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html code:

```
<div id="directoryDropdown">
  <div>
    <div id="toclistitemID6">
      "5"
      ". &nbsp;"
      "Conclusion Page"
      </div>
</div>
```

I need to select the div that has the "Conclusion Page" text. The id for the element is dynamic so I want to use the text but can't get the element to be found.
I have tried the following xpath-s:

1. //div[contains(text(),'Conclusion Page')] - doesn't find the element
2. //div[contains(.,'Conclusion Page')] - finds 8 elements including all parent elements of this one
3. //div[text()[contains(.,'Conclusion Page')]] - finds the parent element div id="directoryDropdown"
4. //div[@id='directoryDropdown']/child::div/child::div[contains(text(),'Conclusion Page')] - 0 elements found
5. //div[contains(text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUDST.png),"Conclusion Page")]/@id - 0 elements found

Can someone please recommend how to build the xpath to select this element? Or use any other locator that allows to select containing text for tests using Java/Selenium? (seems like CSS locators don't have this option)

UPDATE: After I try to copy the text from the element the object starts looking like that (without "5" ".  ") and the element is found. So I guess the problem is that the actual text is inside of the object or is not the first text. Also posting whole html here:

```
<div id="directoryDropdown" xpath="1">
 <div>
 <div id="toclistitemID0"></div>
<div id="toclistitemID1" style="color: rgb(247, 181, 0);"></div>
<div id="toclistitemID2"></div>
<div id="toclistitemID5">Conclusion Page</div>
<div id="toclistitemID6"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never post code/markup as images.  Post as text, formatted as code.   And provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your 1-3 claims.

Comment: Try `//div[contains(text()[1],"Conclusion Page")]/@id`. This should show you it the right `id` was selected.

Comment: Check if this is locating the element -- //div[@id='directoryDropdown']/child::div/child::div[contains(text(),'Conclusion Page')]

Comment: @YaDavMaNish thank you but this xpath doesn't find the element either

Comment: I suspect that the html you posted in the question doesn't really represent the actual html. The expression definitely works on the sample html.

Comment: @JackFleeting updated my question with full html

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//div[contains(child::text(), "Conclusion Page")]
```

Comment: Not finding the element :(

Comment: The xpath works on the sample html : http://jsfiddle.net/9ny38jvm/1/